# Next.js getInitialProps() method not called when reloading static page

Tags: static, next.js

I’m building a **static** site in Next.js. As static sites produce pages with the `.html` extension, I’m using the `as` attribute on my `Link` elements, which allow my pages to be reloaded.

I have now introduced the use of **query strings** to my URL’s so that, when the pages are reloaded, they remember what content to display, by use of the `getInitialProps()` method.

So far, so good, BUT ONLY DURING DEVELOPMENT.

The problem I face is, when the site is exported out as the **static** version, Next.js fails to call the `getInitialProps()` method, hence, when the browser is refreshed, my pages no longer know what to display.

Can anybody help with any of the following:

1. Is there another way to allow **static** pages to be refreshed, **without** the use of the `.html` extension?
2. Is there a way to ensure that the `getInitialProps()` method is called when exporting a **static** site and when **reloading** a page?
3. Is there another way in which I can **retrieve the query string** from the browser URL, as Next.js doesn’t seem to have the ability to access even the top level `window` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getInitialProps` is only available on server-side rendered apps. It runs during development because Next doesn't know if you want your pages to be static or SSR. But when you run `next build && next export`, they become static and `getInitialProps` no longer runs. I believe this is also why next switched to `getServerSideProps` and `getStaticProps` instead of `getInitialProps` (for everything but the `_app.js` page)

In response to your list of questions:

1. Next exports so that you don't have to use/show the HTML extension, but that also depends on your hosting setup. Exporting a static site exports `.html` files, but it's up to your hosting configuration to determine whether or not those are shown.
2. See above and no - there is no way to have `getInitialProps` run on a fully static, exported site. You'd need to switch to a server-side rendered site if you have to use `getInitialProps`.
3. Your static site can retrieve the query string, but it's not going to have it at build time. Instead, you'd need to check for it (usually in `React.useEffect`) when the window object *is* available. On a static site, that's not at buildtime but only at runtime. [Check out this answer on how to get the query string in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) - you can use this in your `useEffect`.

Comment: This is so spot on and so clear, thank you.

1) I will be trying this first, as it seems the least painful.
2) Understood - makes sense and helps with my wider understanding.
3) I've just tested this (not that I don't trust you) and can see the `window` object, so this is my backup plan.